# ng-include causes url to change from localhost/index.html to localhost/index.html#/index.html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-include

I am using angularjs and it automatically appends

`#index.html` to url

`http://localhost/index.html`
so the path will look like

`http://localhost/index.html#/index.html`

when i commented the ng-include wrapped `<div ng-include="'temp.html'></div>` 
the url reverted back to 
`localhost/index.html`

but as i uncommented the `<div ng-include="'temp.html'></div>`
it reverted back to 
`localhost/index.html#/index.html`

so,

1. why is it happening ?
2. is there a work-around ? so that i can use ng-include and keep the url intact .

Note : I am not using any routing

Comment: Couldn't replicate your error. Could post your source code so we can take a look and help you further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several bug reports since angularjs 1.1.5 added this problem:

- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2898
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2898
- and others ...

This bug ist fixed in release 1.2.1 which is available for download.

Changeset: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/d4d34aba6efbd98050235f5b264899bb788117df